# nginx configure /folder run from a different path than the /

Tags: nginx, subdirectory

I am having an issue running /folder from a different path than the main website.

my nginx.conf for that section look like this:

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files               $uri = 404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index           index.php;
           include                 fastcgi_params;
            include                 fastcgi.conf;
    }


location ~ /folder {
        alias /srv/http/folder;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @folder;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include        fastcgi.conf;
        }
}

location @folder {
    rewrite /folder/(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

In the error.log I can see the following:

```
2020/06/03 09:05:26 [error] 25966#25966: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.21.2.46, server: example.com, request: "GET /folder/xxx_v6.15.11/Resources/images/redcaplogo.gif HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex locations are matched from first to last, and the first found match processed by nginx. When you get a request for `/folder/script.php`, it is processed by the first location block. Try to swap this two locations. Additionaly, why are you do not include `fastcgi_params` in your second location block?

**Update**

I did some debugging, lets look at you code (assuming location block already swapped):

```
location ~ /folder {
    alias /srv/http/folder;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @folder;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files               $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    include                 fastcgi.conf;
}

location @folder {
    rewrite /folder/(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

If we get a request `/folder/some/path` (and there is no `some/path` file or directory inside the `folder`), inside the nested location internal nginx variables would have following values:

- `$request_filename`: empty string (there is no real file or folder `/some/path` inside th `folder` directory);
- `$uri`: `/folder/check.php`;
- `$document_root`: `/srv/http/folder`.

If we get a request `/folder/some/path/script.php` (and there is a real PHP script with this name), inside the nested location internal nginx variables would have following values:

- `$request_filename`: `/srv/http/folder/some/path/script.php`;
- `$uri`: `/folder/some/path/check.php`;
- `$document_root`: `/srv/http/folder`.

Additionally, when you get a request for a static resource from your folder, for example `/folder/some/path/static.css`, the `try_files $uri ...` directive will search `folder/some/path/static.css` file in a `/srv/http/folder` directory, which leads to check the existence of `/srv/http/folder/folder/some/path/static.css` file.

One of possible solutions to get a file subpath inside the `folder` directory:

```
location ~ ^/folder(?<subpath>.*) {
    alias /srv/http/folder;
    try_files $subpath $subpath/ @folder;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$subpath;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files               $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    include                 fastcgi.conf;
}

location @folder {
    rewrite ^/folder/(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

This could be simplified if your real `folder` directory name is the same as your `/folder` URI prefix:

```
location ~ ^/folder {
    root /srv/http;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @folder;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
}

...
```

As nginx documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>   alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the root directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>   root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

Comment: I have switched the location orders and added factsgi_param to the location ~ /folder but the error is the same.

Comment: @zozo6015 A really interesting one! Found the cause of problem, see the updated answer.

Comment: It is better since the error has disapeared but the static objects like css, js and images are still not loaded.

Comment: @zozo6015 Updated an answer, please check.

Comment: I cannot use location for static objects because I have multiple locations for /folder type of destinations which each has a different path for the static objects. If I put it inside the location ~ /folder the nginx is complaining that `nginx: [emerg] location "/images/" is outside location "/folder"`

Comment: 1) Do you checked an updated answer? I didn't propose to use additional locations. 2) Of course nginx would complain to such configuration, you should use `location /folder/images/` inside the `location /folder`.